# Gemini API Python {'result': 'error', 'reason': 'InvalidSignature', 'message': 'InvalidSignature'}

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, gemini

I Am getting an error when using the [Gemini API documentation][1] while following the documentation for a Private API invocation.

The json output is:

```
{'result': 'error', 'reason': 'InvalidSignature', 'message': 'InvalidSignature'}.
```

My code:

```
gemini_api_key = getMasterApi()#gets master api key from a json file
gemini_api_secret = getSecretApi().encode()#gets secret api key from a json file
print(gemini_api_secret)
t = datetime.datetime.now() 
payload_nonce =  str(int(time.mktime(t.timetuple())*1000))
payload =  {"request": "/v1/mytrades", "nonce": payload_nonce}
encoded_payload = json.dumps(payload).encode()
b64 = base64.b64encode(encoded_payload)
signature = hmac.new(gemini_api_secret, b64, hashlib.sha384).hexdigest()

request_headers = {
    'Content-Type': "text/plain",
    'Content-Length': "0",
    'X-GEMINI-APIKEY': gemini_api_key,
    'X-GEMINI-PAYLOAD': b64,
    'X-GEMINI-SIGNATURE': signature,
    'Cache-Control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.post(url, headers=request_headers)

my_trades = response.json()
print(my_trades)
 [https://docs.gemini.com/rest-api/#public-api-invocation][1]
```

Comment: any luck getting this to work?

Comment: I had the same problem today. It was working for a few hours and then it just randomly stopped, without me changing anything. Does anybody know why?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and was able to resolve it by creating a new API key with Primary scope (instead of Master scope) and Auditor permissions.

Comment: I tried that and I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using the right URL. If you made an API key using a sandbox account, you have to change the URL to `url = "https://api.sandbox.gemini.com/v1/mytrades"`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the Gemini sandbox, you will need to create your API keys using https://exchange.sandbox.gemini.com/ as opposed to their normal site.

Answer (score 0):

If doing this on your live account and not a sandbox account, when you go to create an API, select 'primary' with 'Fund Management' and 'Trading' permissions. 'Auditor' will not allow you to interact with your funds or place orders.

I had the same issue until I did this.